# AWS Code Build: environment variables not found during CI jobs

Tags: amazon-web-services, continuous-integration, environment-variables, aws-codepipeline, aws-codecommit

I usually name **artifacts** based on the **commits** they have been build from. 
Based on [this documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-env-ref-env-vars.html), `CODEBUILD_WEBHOOK_PREV_COMMIT` is what I am looking for in [AWS Code Build](https://aws.amazon.com/fr/codebuild/)

Here is the `buildspec.yml`

```yaml
phases:
  install: 
    commands:
      - apt-get update -y
  build:
    commands:
      - export $CODEBUILD_WEBHOOK_PREV_COMMIT
      - echo Entered the build phase...
      - echo Build started on `date`
      - mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true
      - for f in ./target/*.car;do mv -- "$f" $(echo $f | sed -E "s/.car$/_${CODEBUILD_WEBHOOK_PREV_COMMIT}.car/") ;done

artifacts:
  files:
    - ./target/*.car
```

Build works but the **commit** does not show in the final `.car` name. I would like to understand why.

### Hypothesis n°1: `VAR`s needs to be explicitly sourced

I tried the following without much success

```yaml
env: 
  variable: 
    - COMMIT="${CODEBUILD_WEBHOOK_PREV_COMMIT}"

phases:
  install: 
    commands:
      - apt-get update -y
  build:
    commands:
      - echo Entered the build phase...
      - echo Build started on `date`
      - mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true
      - carpath=./*_CA/target/*.car
      - for f in $carpath;do mv -- "$f" $(echo $f | sed -E "s/.car$/_${COMMIT}.car/") ;done
```

### `VAR`s are only available to AWS default build container

I am using [Maven's official image](https://hub.docker.com/_/maven) `maven:3.6.3-jdk-8` instead of Amazon's general purpose build image. Are `VAR`s available for custom images? I can't find any clear indication they are not.

Comment: Did you resolve this? I'm having the same issue and I'm at loss why it doesn't work.

Comment: Unfortunately, this migration project has been postponed by the client. Did not have much occasion to work on it since then. I'll update it has soon as I make progress (god knows when...)

Comment: Hey so I figured it out in the meantime after writing initial comment. I put `printenv` in commands to see whats going on and `$CODEBUILD_WEBHOOK_PREV_COMMIT` was completely missing. Use `$CODEBUILD_RESOLVED_SOURCE_VERSION` instead, which is there!

Answer (score 2):

I lost entire afternoon on this, for anyone that is coming here with the same problem, here is how I solved it:

First, I've put `printenv` in commands to see whats going on and `$CODEBUILD_WEBHOOK_PREV_COMMIT` env variable was completely missing. But you can use `$CODEBUILD_RESOLVED_SOURCE_VERSION` instead, which was there!